# My form is automatically submitting when i make a ajax call

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am having a form which will submit list of products to the spring backend

I have two separate buttons
1). Submit button to submit the form
2). Fetch available Stock button to check stock availability

When i click Fetch available stock **button** -- it will invoke a function which will make Ajax call to fetch stock details

But the problem is whenever i click Fetch available stock **button**

Both ajax call for fetching stock data and form submission also happens.

I don't want the form to submit till i press the submit button

**Note:** i am having the form in bootstrap modal

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without the code we can't do match but I suggest in the form submitting code you should use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior of submit button and after you complete all your logic you should submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

add the attribute `type="button"`  to the button